# DataGridView capturing user row selection

Tags: c#, winforms

I am having trouble handling the selections in `DataGridView`.
My grid view contains an amount column. There is a textbox on the form which should display the total amount of the selected grid view rows. Hence I need to capture events when the user selects/ deselects the gridview rows and calculate (add/ subtract) the amount accordingly. I have found two methods of doing it:

1. Using the `RowEnter` and `RowLeave` events. 
   These work fine when user selects/ deselects a single row. However, when the user is selecting multiple rows at one go, the event gets fired only for the last row. Hence, from my total amount only the amount in the last row gets added/ subtracted. Thus making my result erroneous.
2. Using the `RowStateChanged` event.
   This works for multiple rows. However, the event gets fired event if the user scrolls through the datagrid.

Has anyone handled such a scenario. I would like to know which datagrid event I should be using, so that my code executes only when user selects/ deselects rows including multiple rows.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Found the solution. I can use `RowStateChanged` and run my code only if `StateChanged` for the row is `Selected`...

```
private void dgridv_RowStateChanged(object sender, DataGridViewRowStateChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // For any other operation except, StateChanged, do nothing
    if (e.StateChanged != DataGridViewElementStates.Selected) return;

    // Calculate amount code goes here
}
```

Answer (score 9):

I use **SelectionChanged** event or **CellValueChanged** event:

```
        dtGrid.SelectionChanged += DataGridView_SelectionChanged;
        this.dtGrid.DataSource = GetListOfEntities;
        dtGrid.CellValueChanged += DataGridView_CellValueChanged;


    private void DataGridView_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        DataGridViewRow row = dtGrid.Rows[e.RowIndex];
        SetRowProperties(row);
    }

    private void DataGridView_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var rowsCount = dtGrid.SelectedRows.Count;
        if (rowsCount == 0 || rowsCount > 1) return;

        var row = dtGrid.SelectedRows[0];
        if (row == null) return; 
        ResolveActionsForRow(row);
    }
```

Comment: What's SetRowProperties?

Answer (score 6):

I think you can consider the SelectionChanged event:

```
private void DataGridView1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  textbox1.Text = DataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count.ToString();
}
```

Comment: if the grid is in cell select mode it won't be triggered (unless you click on the row header)

Answer (score 3):

You can use [SelectionChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.selectionchanged(v=vs.110).aspx) event and retrieve the row index of the selected cell(s):

```
    private void dataGridView1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (dataGridView1.SelectedCells.Count > 0)
            Do_Something_With_It(dataGridView1.SelectedCells[0].RowIndex);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply capture this in following way, but it is restricted to single row selection only:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Selected row is=" + e.RowIndex);
    //  you can perform (any operation) delete action on selected row like

    dataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(e.RowIndex);
    dataGridView1.Refresh();
}
```

Comment: Not sufficient when user enters a row with keyboard

Answer (score 0):

You can use your first method (row enter row leave) along with the [SelectedRows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.selectedrows.aspx) property. Meaning, when you detect those events, and you need to calculate, instead of using the row from the event args, loop through the SelectedRows and get your total.

Comment: I can't do this, because I need to subtract amount from those records which were selected initially and are not selected now.