# selecting data from a Data Grid view

Tags: c#, .net

I have looked into this and I am not able to find a clear answer on

1. Allowing user to select data from a data grid view on a form.
2. How this can be done programmatically through a button click on the user form after they have selected that information they need

using c#

Comment: Show what you have done so far and please be specific to your question.

Comment: I have got data from a excel file and then put this into a dataGridView in visual stdio 2010 usinf c# and now i wopuld like the user to selecty from this data the data that should be uploaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to enable full row selection in windows forms you can do

```
this.dataGridView1.SelectionMode =
    DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;
this.dataGridView1.MultiSelect = false;
```

if you want to get the selected row, you can do:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    var rowIndex = e.RowIndex;
    var currentRow = dataGridView1.Rows[rowIndex];
    var currentCellValue = dataGridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value.ToString();  
}
```

Comment: would this allow me to pass the data back into a couple of variable in the back ground

Comment: also how can i go about doing this

Comment: the link is for a web application bus mine is a windows applicaion

Comment: so how would i get the selected values and use them sorry about i am a novice with c#

Comment: would this allow me to store multiple rows of data.

Comment: Have a look at this question. It will tell you what you want. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1027360/datagridview-capturing-user-row-selection

Comment: this wouldnt work for me as this we merge the information together i want to read in multiple rows.

Comment: why can't you use RowStateChanged event of DataGridview?

Comment: because i dont want to change the state of the row only would like to copy that information to use to create a chart from, it...

Comment: if (e.StateChanged != DataGridViewElementStates.Selected) checks for the state, it does not change the state.

Comment: how would i hole the values in the selected cells and create a chart from that stored data.

Answer (score 0):

One possible way to get the data from DataGridView:

```
var i = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index;
var value1 = DataGridView1.Item(0, i).Value
var value2 = DataGridView1.Item(1, i).Value
var value3 = DataGridView1.Item(2, i).Value
```

You may also refer to following references:

http://www.dotnetperls.com/datagridview

http://www.dotnetperls.com/datagridview-tutorial

Comment: this is done through hard coding how would i do iot from the actual from itself from using a button click